# how to get procedure arguments in sybase ?

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

Is there a way I can select the arguments of a procedure in Sybase for example in oracle there is this

```
select * from user_arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for the **values** assigned to the stored proc's parameters ... no, there is no feature like 'select * from user_arguments' in Sybase ASE.

If on the other hand you're just looking for the **names** of the stored proc's parameters ... you could select the parameter names (and datatypes) from **syscolumns**, eg:

```
select ... from syscolumns where id = @@procid
```

where **@@procid** is the object id of the currently executing procedure.

NOTE: It gets a bit more complicated if the procedure exists in a different database as you'll then need to reference 'different_dbname'..syscolumns.

Comment: I tried to use syscomments but also no help , by the way in the tag i specify sybase ase

Comment: @Moudiz: my apologies, I haven't had my morning dose of caffeine yet ... totally glossed over the tags; have updated my answer; and no, syscomments won't do you any good